# Evaluate the long multiplication

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

> Evaluate Q1:$[-100\times (-99)] \times [-99 \times (-98)] \times [-98 \times (-97)]..... (97\times 98)\times (98 \times 99) \times (99 \times 100)$

And

> Evaluate Q2:$(-100-98) \times (-99-97) \times (-98-96).....(96+98) \times (97+99) \times (98+100)$ (Clue:there is a pattern, but is "disrupted" by the $+(-)$ property.

Then, after evaluating this, solve the fraction with the answers you got previously.

$\frac {Q1  evalution} {Q2   evaluation}$

Is a scientific calculator able to calculate the result?(Assuming the calulator cannot calculate answers bigger than 10000000000)(Yeah, a lousy scientific calculator that fails to understand how to put in a standard number form (like for example $3.1839\times10^{65}$)

Comment: Wish I could ask why I get a negative score on this.Is it because it sounds like under "math"? Or did I catergerise these wrongly?

Comment: unfortunately, people downvote w/o saying why.  I'm thinking because the puzzle is not well thought out/ busy work.  And answer seems problematic (i.e., the puzzle isn't well thought out.)

Comment: I suspect it was downvoted because it's asking for a simple calculation. This isn't a puzzle.

Comment: @Jiminion its problematic when you cannot guess the little pattern. The question looks mathematically heavy, but if you know the simple math, you can simply do this without thinking that much.Otherwise, I would have went to the maths stack exchange

Comment: @IanMacDonald ahh, I see.Tyen where I can pist this type of question to? If I post on maths stack exchange and know the answer, people would also downvote isnt it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both multiplications have a factor of 0.
The first one obviously and the other one in the factor (-1+1).
So the result is 0 in both cases.
0/0 doesn't exists so the second question hasn't an answer.

Comment: Yeap.Not meant to be heavy on mathematics.You got it.

Comment: A gold badge but no silver badges - that must be pretty rare!